# Uninstalling many applications at once Android

Tags: android, uninstall

I'm looking for a program that can uninstall many applications at once Android. I want to simply select a bunch of applications, then hitting on one single button would be enough to uninstall all the selected applications. I tried [Easy Uninstaller App Uninstall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.uninstaller&hl=en) but I have to perform 3 clicks for each application. Free and working with an unrooted Android is better.

I use a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2 and Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.2.

Comment: I used [Go Launcher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex). It has an app manager to remove many apps at once. The problem is that you still have to confirm the uninstall for each app (1 click per app). I removed the launcher app afterwards. I don't think you can skip the confirmation step without rooting your device. I miss the old Play Store where we could [remove the apps using the website](http://thetechjournal.com/how-to/tutorial-how-to-uninstall-android-apps-via-google-play-web-site.xhtml).

Comment: [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) allows you to uninstall apps using their website, but it still requires the 1-click confirmation step for each app

Answer (score 2):

I found few apps matching your requirement:

- [Batch Uninstall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.menue.BatchUninstall&hl=en) - Warning: This one requires too much permissions. Looks almost like a spyware.
- [Batch Uninstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.wiagames.batchuninstaller)

Answer (score 2):

As usual when looking for an *Android* app, I can recommend one of my app listings: [Organize Apps](http://android.qumran.org/catmin/applists/category/named/apps_organize) has a section on **[Remove Apps](http://android.qumran.org/catmin/applists/category/named/apps_organize#group_4)**. I rarely have the necessarity to remove a bunch of apps at once (and if so, the the "alternative solution" at the end of my answer), so I cannot present much "personal experience", but still:

If you're looking for an app requiring as little permissions as possible: **[Multi Uninstaller](http://www.appbrain.com/app/vee.vee.uninstaller)** (presenting itself as "Rabbit Uninstaller") most likely is your candidate (only requesting Internet and NetworkState). With a 4.6 rating it's well received. An image says more than 1,000 words, so let me summarize your requirements that way:

[image: Nulti Uninstaller]
<sup>*Multi Uninstaller:* Select and uninstall apps (source: Google Play; click image for larger variant)</sup>

For possible alternatives, be welcome on my site (link above). On the other hand, if you know the package name or, even better, have them in a file already, you can save yourself a lot of clicks using the command-line:

```
adb shell pm uninstall com.package.name
```

uninstalls apps as well, and you just had to start the script :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=es_419). Its main function is as a file manager, but also has numerous other features, one of which is precisely app backup/uninstall:

[image: ES File Explorer uninstall screen]

Here you can select as many apps as you like and an uninstall option will appear, that will delete them all together. I've not tried it (no test pig in my phone :D) but I think it still needs to confirm each app individually, due to the way Android manages uninstalls. Doesn't requires root, but can make use of it if available to also manage system apps.